# Error message when calling watir-webdriver test with Arguments

Tags: watir-webdriver, testunit

I'm trying to fix my tests so I can call them from the command line with enviromental variables, like what browser.

I call it in a command prompt:
ruby watir1_environment.rb -BROWSER=chrome

And get the following error message:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:49:in `process_args': invalid option: -BROWSER=chrome (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:891:in `_run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325:in `block in autorun'
```

This is the code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "test/unit"
require "watir-webdriver"


class TestingEnvironments < Test::Unit::TestCase
def setup
case ENV['BROWSER']
  when 'ff', 'Firefox'
  @b = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  browser_name = 'Firefox'
when 'chrome'
  @b = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  browser_name = 'Chrome'
when 'debug'
  debug_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  debug_profile.add_extension "firebug-1.9.1-fx.xpi"
  @b = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => debug_profile
  browser_name = 'Firefox (Firebug)'
when 'mobile'
  mobile_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  mobile_profile['general.useragent.override'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en)
  AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0
  Mobile/1A535b Safari/419.3"
  @b = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => mobile_profile
  browser_name = 'Mobile'
when 'headless'
  headless_profile = Headless.new
  headless_profile.start
  @b = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  browser_name = 'Firefox'
else
 @b = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
 browser_name = 'Firefox'
end
end

def test
  {Test Code}
end
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Windows ENV variables from the command line by using the `set` command.

```
C:\> SET BROWSER=chrome
C:\> ruby watir1_environment.rb
```

You can find out more about `set` at http://ss64.com/nt/set.html.

Alternatively, rather than using `ENV['BROWSER']` you can access the [`ARGV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-argv) variable, which is an array of arguments passed at the command line. Just change your case statement to:

```
case ARGV[0]
```

This requires only the keyword, and not the `-BROWSER=`.

```
C:\> ruby watir1_environment.rb chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

I pass the variables in without the dash and it works fine.

```
ruby watir1_environment.rb BROWSER=chrome
```

I also use the [Fig_Newton gem](https://github.com/cheezy/fig_newton) for variable's that I use regularly.